# How to watch an object within object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

I have tried different ways to access an Array, I haven't been able

This is my array:

```
Sites [ 
{
    "0": { 
        "catf": 
        { 
            "2": { "cats": { "id": "9" } }, 
            "4": { "cats": { "id": "12" } }, 
            "5": { "cats": { "id": "13" } } 
        } 
    } 
}, 
{ 
    "1": { 
        "catf": 
        { 
            "2": { "cats": { "id": "10" } }, 
            "4": { "cats": { "id": "11" } } 
        } 
    } 
}]
```

This is how I am trying to access the array

```
$scope.proposal2.sites[0].catf[2];
```

this is the error

```
Cannot read property '2' of undefined
```

When I print `console.log($scope.proposal2.sites[0])` I got this

```
 Object {0: Object, $$hashKey: "00L"} >0: Object >catf: Object >2: Object >cats: Object id: >"10"
```

How could I access it?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't know why you need this helluva structure but you can try `$scope.proposal2.sites[0][0].catf[2]` to access what you need

Comment: your biggest issue is having severely overcomplicated the initial data structure. If you don't control the API I would remap it to cleaner structure when you receive it

Comment: The structure is complex because I need to create complex nested array that is withing sites(n sites) there are devices within devices categories withing categories products.

Comment: nesting is not what i mean, it's the use of array indexes as object keys that makes no sense and makes it difficult to deal with the data objects themselves. There are much simpler ways to approach this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem is: $scope.proposal2.sites[0][0].catf[2]

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.proposal2.sites[0].catf[2];
```

In the above line of code, `sites` is an array object, so here you could access the data, but   `catf` is an `Object`, so you are getting issue like "Cannot read property '2' of undefined".

Answer (score 1):

In your code you declared array with two objects. To access first of them you should use `$scope.proposal2.sites[0]`. Then this object have only one key - `0`:

```
{
    "0": { 
        "catf": 
        { 
            "2": { "cats": { "id": "9" } }, 
            "4": { "cats": { "id": "12" } }, 
            "5": { "cats": { "id": "13" } } 
        } 
    } 
},
```

so you accessing it with `$scope.proposal2.sites[0][0]` to get object with only one key `catf`:

```
{ 
   "catf":{ 
       "2": { "cats": { "id": "10" } }, 
       "4": { "cats": { "id": "11" } } 
   }
}
```

so now you use `$scope.proposal2.sites[0][0].catf[2]` to access what you want.

Also I agreed with charlietfl`s comments in that your structure looks too complicated and maybe you would like to have something like this:

```
[ 
  {"catf": { 
    "2": { "cats": { "id": "9" } }, 
    "4": { "cats": { "id": "12" } }, 
    "5": { "cats": { "id": "13" } } 
    }
  },
  {"catf": { 
    "2": { "cats": { "id": "10" } }, 
    "4": { "cats": { "id": "11" } } 
    }
  }
]
```

and access it with `$scope.proposal2.sites[0].catf[2]`

Also I believe than even this structure can (and should) be simplified, but to go with it, you should give more information about your task.

Comment: More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27579320/angularjs-radio-buttons-in-nested-accordion-do-not-keep-values